# Using calculations in Ruby and Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

First let me apologize for a seemingly easy question, but being new to rails, ruby and programming I feel like I've exhausted the "New to Rails" tutorials out there.

Here's what I'm up against.

I have a Users model and Institution Model that have a "has_many :through => :company_reps" relationship.

The user has basic fields (name, email, password) (I'm using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise))

The Institution has many fields but the relevant ones are (client = boolean, lead = boolean, demo_date = date/time)
To complicate it further each Institution can have one or two users but most only have one.

We are holding a contest for the users and I need to award points to each user based on the demo_date field and client field.

So firstly what I need to do is give each user 10 points that is related to an institution that is a client, unless that institution has 2 users in which case I need to give those two users 5 points each.

Secondly I need to give all users 1 point that are related to an institution that has a demo date after Feb. 2012.

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.2.8 and MySQL

- So, how can I accomplish this?
- Should I create a new table and model to store the points, if so how do I save the calculations?
- Should I put all the calculations in the User or Institution Model?

As always thank you for the help.

**MySQL Institution Info**

```
CREATE TABLE `institutions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `state_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `clientdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `street` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `source2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `demodate1` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `demodate2` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `demodate3` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `client` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prospect` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `alead` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notcontacted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7805 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Institution Model**

```
class Institution < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :company, :phone, :assets, :clientdate, :street, :city, :state_id, :zip, :source, :source2, :demodate1, :demodate2, :demodate3, :client, :prospect, :alead, :notcontacted
  belongs_to :state
  has_many :users, :through => :company_reps
  has_many :company_reps

end
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  has_many :states, :through => :rep_areas
  has_many :institutions, :through => :company_reps
  has_many :rep_areas
  has_many :company_reps

  def name 
    first_name + " " + last_name
  end


end
```

**Company Rep Model**

```
class CompanyRep < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :institution
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update (since my first attempt was wrongly assuming `User has_one :institution`**

The simplest option would be to do the basic calculation on the `Institution` model to establish how many points the institution is "worth", and then sum that value to calculate the user's points.

```
# Institution
def points
  points_for_client + points_for_demo_date
end

private

def points_for_client
  if client?
    10 / users.count
  else
    0
  end
end

def points_for_demo_date
  if demo_date.present? && demo_date >= Date.new(2012, 3, 1)
    1
  else
    0
  end
end
```

Note that you could condense those `if` statements into one-liners with the ternary operator `? :` if you prefer. Also note that I assumed "after February" to mean "from March 1 onwards".

The check for a nil `demo_date` is also a matter of taste. Take your pick from

```
# Verbose, but IMO intention-revealing
demo_date.present? && demo_date >= Date.new(...)

# Perhaps more idiomatic, since nil is falsy
demo_date && demo_date >= Date.new(...)

# Take advantage of the fact that >= is just another method
# Concise, but I think it's a bit yuk!
demo_date.try :>=, Date.new(...)
```

Now that each institution is worth a certain number of points, it's fairly simple to sum them up:

```
# User
def points
  institutions.inject(0) {|sum, institution| sum + institution.points }
end
```

Check out [the docs for `inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) if you're not familiar with it, it's a nifty little method.

As far as performance goes, this is suboptimal. A basic improvement would be to memoize the results:

```
# Institution
def points
  @points ||= points_for_client + points_for_demo_date
end

# User
def points
  @points ||= institutions.inject ...
end
```

so that further calls of `points` in the same request don't recalculate the value. That's ok as long as the `client` and `demo_date` don't change while the `User` object is still alive:

```
some_user.points   #=> 0
some_user.institution.client = true
some_user.points   #=> 0 ... oops
```

The `User` object will be recreated the next request, so this might not be a problem (it depends on how these fields change).

You could also add a `points` field to the `User` and thus save the value in the database, using the original version as an `update_points` method instead

```
def update_points
  self.points = institutions.inject ...
end
```

However, working out when to recalculate the value is then going to be an issue.

My suggestion would be to keep it as simple as possible and avoid premature optimization. It's a relatively simple calculation so it's not going to be a big performance issue, as long as you don't have a huge number of users and institutions or a lot of requests going on.

Comment: One other question. When I do a rails console to try out the code. I'll do something like u = User.find(1). And then u.points I get undefined method `client?' . Is this due to the user having more than one institution?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread the question, I was working on the assumption that `User has_one :institution`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've got it semi-working now. I say semi because if I remove the point_for_demo_date method I can do User.find(1).points and return the sum. But if I leave the point_for_demo_date method in I get the following error: NoMethodError: undefined method `>=' for nil:NilClass.

Comment: Ah, if `demo_date` can be nil, then you need to check for that. Updating :)

Comment: Andy...thanks man. I'd give you more points if I could. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

Points accumulate to `User`s, so it would seem to make sense to add a method call on the `User` class which returns the number of points they've accumulated.

I'd start on this by just writing a method that computed the total points each time it's called, with some unit tests to make sure the computation is right.  I wouldn't save the results at first - depending on how many objects you have, how often you need to compute points, etc, you may not need to save it at all.